# Why is (False and False or True) true, if "and" makes any false propagate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

`2>3` is false. For `and`, if there is one false in the whole expression, it should return false.

```
print(3>2 and 2>3 and 7>5 or 1>0)
```

Thank you,

Comment: Please try to write your question title to be as self-explanatory as possible, so people don't need to click through and read the question body before they know if its answers will be helpful to them; I've tried to edit towards that end myself here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Did you think it would be parsed as `3>2 and 2>3 and (7>5 or 1>0)`? My first thought was that you thought they had the same precedence, but that would produce the same result: `((3>2 and 2>3) and 7>5) or 1>0`.

Answer (score 6):

`and` has higher [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `or`, so it's equivalent to

```
print((3>2 and 2>3 and 7>5) or 1>0)
```

Since `1>0` is true, and `or` is true if either of its arguments is true, the whole expression is true.

I recommend using explicit parentheses whenever you have a mixture of `and` and `or`, since the default grouping is often not what you intend. It also differs between languages, so if you're used to one language you may have the wrong intuition when you write in another language.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what languages have the opposite precedence? It seems strange since I was taught that boolean AND is basically multiplication and boolean OR is basically addition, so BEDMAS applies.

Comment: @wjandrea I thought MySQL had equal precedence, but I'm wrong.

Comment: Probably not, but I'm pretty sure I've seen some language where they're equal. I just don't remember what it is now.

Comment: @Barmar Oops, I deleted my comment after you edited yours. Anyway, looks like it's sh that has the same precedence: `true || echo aaa && echo bbb` prints `bbb`. Although, to me that makes more sense because it's not really an expression; it's actually called a "list" in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03) and [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html).

Answer (score 0):

Python is doing this internally.

```
print((3>2 and 2>3 and 7>5) or 1>0)
```

For more understanding, [Precedence and Associativity of Operators in Python - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/precedence-and-associativity-of-operators-in-python/)